# Google Speech Recognition doesn't work because of colliding threads Qt C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I'm using Google's Speech-To-Text API in my Qt C++ application.

[Google's C++ documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/streaming_transcribe.cc) is helpful but to an extent.

In my code below, if I uncomment

> std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

The speech recognition is working, but not properly - it's skipping some words. But without this line, it doesn't work at all. I think that's because the while loop of **MicrophoneThreadMain()** collide with the while loop of **start_speech_to_text()**. But I'm not sure.

I want these two functions to run side-by-side simultaneously, without interruptions, and with no delays.
I tried to use QThreads and Signal and Slots but couldn’t make it work.

**speech_to_text.cpp**

```
#include "speechtotext.h"

using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognitionConfig;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::RecognitionConfig;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::Speech;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognizeRequest;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognizeResponse;

SpeechToText::SpeechToText(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void SpeechToText::initialize()
{
    QAudioFormat qtFormat;

    // Get default audio input device
    QAudioDeviceInfo qtInfo = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();

    // Set the audio format settings
    qtFormat.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    qtFormat.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::Endian::LittleEndian);
    qtFormat.setChannelCount(1);
    qtFormat.setSampleRate(16000);
    qtFormat.setSampleSize(16);
    qtFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

    // Check whether the format is supported
    if (!qtInfo.isFormatSupported(qtFormat)) {
        qWarning() << "Default format is not supported";
        exit(3);
    }

    // Instantiate QAudioInput with the settings
    audioInput = new QAudioInput(qtFormat);

    // Start receiving data from audio input
    ioDevice = audioInput->start();

    emit finished_initializing();
}

void SpeechToText::MicrophoneThreadMain(grpc::ClientReaderWriterInterface<StreamingRecognizeRequest,
                                      StreamingRecognizeResponse> *streamer)
{
    StreamingRecognizeRequest request;
    std::size_t size_read;

    while(true)
    {
        audioDataBuffer.append(ioDevice->readAll());
        size_read = audioDataBuffer.size();
        // And write the chunk to the stream.
        request.set_audio_content(&audioDataBuffer.data()[0], size_read);
        std::cout << "Sending " << size_read / 1024 << "k bytes." << std::endl;
        streamer->Write(request);
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void SpeechToText::start_speech_to_text()
{
    StreamingRecognizeRequest request;

    auto *streaming_config   = request.mutable_streaming_config();
    RecognitionConfig *recognition_config = new RecognitionConfig();

    recognition_config->set_language_code("en-US");
    recognition_config->set_sample_rate_hertz(16000);
    recognition_config->set_encoding(RecognitionConfig::LINEAR16);
    streaming_config->set_allocated_config(recognition_config);

    // Create a Speech Stub connected to the speech service.
    auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();
    auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("speech.googleapis.com", creds);
    std::unique_ptr<Speech::Stub> speech(Speech::NewStub(channel));

    // Begin a stream.
    grpc::ClientContext context;
    auto streamer = speech->StreamingRecognize(&context);

    // Write the first request, containing the config only.
    streaming_config->set_interim_results(true);
    streamer->Write(request);

    // The microphone thread writes the audio content.
    std::thread microphone_thread(&SpeechToText::MicrophoneThreadMain, this, streamer.get());

    // Read responses.
    StreamingRecognizeResponse response;
    while (streamer->Read(&response)) // Returns false when no more to read.
    {
        // Dump the transcript of all the results.
        for (int r = 0; r < response.results_size(); ++r)
        {
            auto result = response.results(r);
            std::cout << "Result stability: " << result.stability() << std::endl;
            for (int a = 0; a < result.alternatives_size(); ++a)
            {
                auto alternative = result.alternatives(a);
                std::cout << alternative.confidence() << "\t"
                        << alternative.transcript() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    grpc::Status status = streamer->Finish();
    microphone_thread.join();
    if (!status.ok()) {
      // Report the RPC failure.
      qDebug() << "error RPC";
      std::cerr << status.error_message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**speech_to_text.h**

```
#ifndef SPEECHTOTEXT_H
#define SPEECHTOTEXT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

#include <QtMultimedia>
#include <QtMultimedia/QAudioInput>
#include <QAudioDeviceInfo>
#include <QAudioFormat>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QMutex>

#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>
#include "google/cloud/speech/v1/cloud_speech.grpc.pb.h"

using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognitionConfig;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::RecognitionConfig;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::Speech;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognizeRequest;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognizeResponse;

class SpeechToText : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SpeechToText(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void finished_initializing();
    void finished_speech_to_text(QString);

public slots:
    void initialize();
    void start_speech_to_text();

private:
    void MicrophoneThreadMain(grpc::ClientReaderWriterInterface<StreamingRecognizeRequest,
                                          StreamingRecognizeResponse> *);

    QAudioInput *audioInput;
    QIODevice *ioDevice;
    QByteArray audioDataBuffer;
};

#endif // SPEECHTOTEXT_H
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Also, the google code in the link you provide calls `WritesDone` after Write, when there is nothing to write. Are you sure you are always writing something, i.e size_read is never 0 ?

Comment: And if you lose some words, it might be because the audio buffer is too small : maybe using setBuffer with a "big enough buffer" would help, like here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/71129/voip-qtcpsoket-audio-streaming/5

Comment: @iMajuscule Thanks for the info. GDPR's answer seems less hackish so I'll look into that first.

Answer (score 2):

I post here the solution to my problem. Thanks @allquixotic for all the helpful information.

**in mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::setUpMicrophoneRecorder()
{
    microphone_thread = new QThread(this);
    microphone_recorder_engine.moveToThread(microphone_thread);

    connect(microphone_thread, SIGNAL(started()), &microphone_recorder_engine, SLOT(start_listen()));
    connect(&microphone_recorder_engine, &MicrophoneRecorder::microphone_data_raw,
            this, [this] (const QByteArray &data) {
        this->speech_to_text_engine.listen(data);
    });

    microphone_thread->start();
}

void MainWindow::setUpSpeechToTextEngine()
{
    speech_to_text_thread = new QThread(this);
    speech_to_text_engine.moveToThread(speech_to_text_thread);

    connect(speech_to_text_thread, SIGNAL(started()), &speech_to_text_engine, SLOT(initialize()));
    connect(&speech_to_text_engine, SIGNAL(finished_speech_to_text(QString)), this, SLOT(process_user_input(QString)));

    speech_to_text_thread->start();
}
```

**microphonerecorder.h**

```
#ifndef MICROPHONERECORDER_H
#define MICROPHONERECORDER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtMultimedia>
#include <QtMultimedia/QAudioInput>
#include <QAudioDeviceInfo>
#include <QAudioFormat>
#include <QIODevice>

class MicrophoneRecorder : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MicrophoneRecorder(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void microphone_data_raw(const QByteArray &);

public slots:
    void start_listen();

private slots:
    void listen(const QByteArray &);

private:
    QAudioInput *audioInput;
    QIODevice *ioDevice;
    QByteArray audioDataBuffer;
};

#endif // MICROPHONERECORDER_H
```

**microphonerecorder.cpp**

```
#include "microphonerecorder.h"

MicrophoneRecorder::MicrophoneRecorder(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void MicrophoneRecorder::listen(const QByteArray &audioData)
{
    emit microphone_data_raw(audioData);
}

void MicrophoneRecorder::start_listen()
{
    QAudioFormat qtFormat;

    // Get default audio input device
    QAudioDeviceInfo qtInfo = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();

    // Set the audio format settings
    qtFormat.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    qtFormat.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::Endian::LittleEndian);
    qtFormat.setChannelCount(1);
    qtFormat.setSampleRate(16000);
    qtFormat.setSampleSize(16);
    qtFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

    // Check whether the format is supported
    if (!qtInfo.isFormatSupported(qtFormat)) {
        qWarning() << "Default format is not supported";
        exit(3);
    }

    // Instantiate QAudioInput with the settings
    audioInput = new QAudioInput(qtFormat);

    // Start receiving data from audio input
    ioDevice = audioInput->start();

    // Listen to the received data for wake words
    QObject::connect(ioDevice, &QIODevice::readyRead, [=] {
        listen(ioDevice->readAll());
    });
}
```

**speechtotext.h**

```
#ifndef SPEECHTOTEXT_H
#define SPEECHTOTEXT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDateTime>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

#include <QtMultimedia>
#include <QtMultimedia/QAudioInput>
#include <QAudioDeviceInfo>
#include <QAudioFormat>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QMutex>

#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>
#include "google/cloud/speech/v1/cloud_speech.grpc.pb.h"

using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognitionConfig;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::RecognitionConfig;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::Speech;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognizeRequest;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognizeResponse;

class SpeechToText : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SpeechToText(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void finished_initializing();
    void in_speech_to_text();
    void out_of_speech_to_text();
    void finished_speech_to_text(QString);

public slots:
    void initialize();
    void listen(const QByteArray &);
    void start_speech_to_text();

private:
    void MicrophoneThreadMain(grpc::ClientReaderWriterInterface<StreamingRecognizeRequest,
                                          StreamingRecognizeResponse> *);
    void StreamerThread(grpc::ClientReaderWriterInterface<StreamingRecognizeRequest,
                                          StreamingRecognizeResponse> *);

    QByteArray audioDataBuffer;
    int m_start_time;
};

#endif // SPEECHTOTEXT_H
```

**speechtotext.cpp**

```
#include "speechtotext.h"

using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognitionConfig;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::RecognitionConfig;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::Speech;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognizeRequest;
using google::cloud::speech::v1::StreamingRecognizeResponse;

SpeechToText::SpeechToText(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void SpeechToText::initialize()
{
    emit finished_initializing();
}

void SpeechToText::MicrophoneThreadMain(grpc::ClientReaderWriterInterface<StreamingRecognizeRequest,
                                        StreamingRecognizeResponse> *streamer)
{
    StreamingRecognizeRequest request;
    std::size_t size_read;
    while (time(0) - m_start_time <= TIME_RECOGNITION)
    {
        int chunk_size = 64 * 1024;
        if (audioDataBuffer.size() >= chunk_size)
        {
            QByteArray bytes_read = QByteArray(audioDataBuffer);
            size_read = std::size_t(bytes_read.size());

            // And write the chunk to the stream.
            request.set_audio_content(&bytes_read.data()[0], size_read);

            bool ok = streamer->Write(request);
            /*if (ok)
            {
                std::cout << "Sending " << size_read / 1024 << "k bytes." << std::endl;
            }*/

            audioDataBuffer.clear();
            audioDataBuffer.resize(0);
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
    }

    qDebug() << "Out of speech recognition: " << end_date;

    emit out_of_speech_to_text();

    streamer->WritesDone();
}

void SpeechToText::StreamerThread(grpc::ClientReaderWriterInterface<StreamingRecognizeRequest,
                                      StreamingRecognizeResponse> *streamer)
{
    // Read responses.
    StreamingRecognizeResponse response;

    while (time(0) - m_start_time <= TIME_RECOGNITION)
    {
        if(streamer->Read(&response)) // Returns false when no more to read.
        {
            // Dump the transcript of all the results.
            if (response.results_size() > 0)
            {
                auto result = response.results(0);
                if (result.alternatives_size() > 0)
                {
                    auto alternative = result.alternatives(0);
                    auto transcript = QString::fromStdString(alternative.transcript());
                    if (result.is_final())
                    {
                        qDebug() << "Speech recognition: " << transcript;

                        emit finished_speech_to_text(transcript);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void SpeechToText::listen(const QByteArray &audioData)
{
    audioDataBuffer.append(audioData);
}

void SpeechToText::start_speech_to_text()
{
    qDebug() << "in start_speech_to_text: " << start_date;

    emit in_speech_to_text();

    m_start_time = time(0);
    audioDataBuffer.clear();
    audioDataBuffer.resize(0);

    StreamingRecognizeRequest request;

    auto *streaming_config   = request.mutable_streaming_config();
    RecognitionConfig *recognition_config = new RecognitionConfig();

    recognition_config->set_language_code("en-US");
    recognition_config->set_sample_rate_hertz(16000);
    recognition_config->set_encoding(RecognitionConfig::LINEAR16);
    streaming_config->set_allocated_config(recognition_config);

    // Create a Speech Stub connected to the speech service.
    auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();
    auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("speech.googleapis.com", creds);
    std::unique_ptr<Speech::Stub> speech(Speech::NewStub(channel));

    // Begin a stream.
    grpc::ClientContext context;
    auto streamer = speech->StreamingRecognize(&context);

    // Write the first request, containing the config only.
    streaming_config->set_interim_results(true);
    streamer->Write(request);

    // The microphone thread writes the audio content.
    std::thread microphone_thread(&SpeechToText::MicrophoneThreadMain, this, streamer.get());
    std::thread streamer_thread(&SpeechToText::StreamerThread, this, streamer.get());

    microphone_thread.join();
    streamer_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: Hi, i  am using your solution, but could you help me how to build google API?

Answer (score 1):

- You should really follow Google's example and only do 64k at a time.
- You should use `WritesDone()` on the `streamer` when you intend the request to be shipped to Google's server.
- It appears that you aren't ever clearing out your QByteArray's data, so it will just pile up over time with each successive `append` call on your QByteArray. Since you're using a pointer to the first element of data in the underlying array, each time you run through your loop, you're sending the entire audio data that's been captured up to that point to `streamer`. I suggest a nested loop that calls `QIODevice::read(char *data, qint64 maxSize)` repeatedly until your `QByteArray` has exactly 64KB. You'll need to handle a return value of -1 indicating end of stream, and adjust `maxSize` downwards based on how much more data is needed to fill your array up to 64k. Requests to Google's API with too little data (e.g. just a couple of bytes as your current loop appears to do at first) may get you rate-limited, or create upstream congestion on the Internet connection due to the high protocol overhead to data ratio. Also it's probably easier to handle this with a plain C-style array of a fixed size (64k) rather than a QByteArray because you don't need resizing, and AFAIK `QByteArray::clear()` could cause memory allocation (not great for performance). To avoid re-sending old data on a short write (e.g. when the microphone stream closes before the 64k buffer is full), you should also `memset(array, 0, sizeof array);` after each `ClientReaderWriterInterface::WritesDone()` call.
- If the network can't keep up with the incoming microphone data, you may end up with an overrun situation on the `QAudioInput` where it runs out of local buffer to store the audio. More buffering makes this less likely but also decreases responsiveness. You may want to just buffer all the data that comes off of the `QAudioInput` into an unbounded `QByteArray` and read out of *that* 64k at a time (you can do so by wrapping it in a `QBuffer` and all your code dealing with `QIODevice` in `MicrophoneThreadMain()` will be compatible.) I think, normally, for projects like yours, the user would prefer to have worse responsiveness, as opposed to having to repeat themselves, in case of a network related overrun. But there's probably a threshold - maybe 5 seconds or so - after which the buffered data might become "out of date" as the user may try speaking into the mic again, causing a weird effect of multiple STT events happening in rapid succession once the upstream bottleneck frees up.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed reply, I will try to implement your suggestions. Already by sending just 64k at a time the speech recognition works well. I just need to figure out all the other important stuff you mentioned. The thing is I'm not good with C type of variables, but I will try my best. I will post my solution here with the code so other people could benefit.